# Box Shadow works incorrectly on focus in input

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

```
<div class="group">
        <input placeholder="Номер карты" class="inpts inpt-card">
        <input placeholder="Владелец карты" class="inpts inpt-owner">
        <input placeholder="ММ/ГГ" class="inpt-mm small-inpts mmgg">
        <input placeholder="CVC" class="inpt-cvc small-inpts cvc">
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

All code at - https://jsfiddle.net/romariokbn/pspb5urc/

I want box-shadow on all of the focused inpts, but some sides of them is under the other inpts. Z-index changes doesnt work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just add the css property like shown below

**position: relative;**

EDIT: no jquery / js code needed imo

```
.inpts:focus, .small-inpts:focus { 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #fbb040;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #fbb040;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #fbb040;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you really wish to affect all inputs on this page add it within "input"

```
input {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pspb5urc/2/)

Comment: Hi, it is the best way to solve it! But I didnt underastand why position:relative makes this problem solved??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position take a look at this reference it should make it clear what happens with an element with the default position: static

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to change the z-index property of the input you focus on, then revert the z-index value when you focus out:

```
$("input").on("focusin", function(){
    $(this).css("z-index", 1);
});
$("input").on("focusout", function(){
    $(this).css("z-index", 0);
});
```

You'll also need to add the following CSS to the input elements for the z-index rule to apply:

```
input {
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

EDIT: updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pspb5urc/1/